# Any way to link to a time slice of Twitter posts?

Tags: twitter

I am interested in linking to a sequence of tweets by a single user - starting and ending with specific tweets. Basically, due to the constraints, people often tweet a series of short posts that are best viewed together. I wonder if there is a way to refer to them as such (for example by providing starting and ending tweet IDs).

Answer (score 3):

You can't choose the start and end message IDs, but you can use a date range.

```
from:codinghorror since:2014-10-01 until:2014-10-05
```

The above search will give you all of the tweets from Jeff Atwood from October 1 to October 5.

([Twitter Advanced Search Operators](https://support.twitter.com/articles/71577-using-advanced-search))

Answer (score 2):

If you have TweetDeck you can [create a timeline or collection of tweets](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/custom-timelines-in-tweetdeck). You'll select the tweets you want to show together and then have a URL that you can tweet out or post elsewhere that will show the tweets you've grouped.

You can also use something like [Storify](https://storify.com/tour) which does the same thing, but in addition, allow you to include relevant posts from other sites and social networks if you wanted some other context.